# Python - Write to file is written as one long line ['text\n...text\n...'] - need to have it as the original

Tags: python

I`m reading a log file which has several lines and write it to a text file.
the output is written to the file as one long line : ['\Bla Bla Bla\n Bla Bla Bla\n']
In original file it looks OK line by line. The reading is done like that:

```
text_file = open('my_file.log', 'rb')
lines = text_file.readlines()
    lines = lines[100:150] #line numbers range
    x = open(r"LocalLogFile.txt", "a")
    x.write(lines)
```

Any ideas how to solve it so it will look like original file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. Opening a text file in binary mode
2. Reading the entire file into memory
3. Trying to write a *list* to the new file instead of a number of individual lines.

Use `itertools.islice` to create a new iterator that skips the first 100 lines, then yields the next 400 lines, which you can iterate over using an ordinary `for` loop to write to the output file.

```
from itertools import islice


with open('my_file.log', 'r') as f:
    with open('LocalLogFile.txt', 'a') as x:
        for line in islice(f, 100, 150):
            print(line, file=x, end='')
```

Some might prefer a single `with` statement:

```
with open('my_file.log', 'r') as f, open('LocalLogFile.txt', 'a') as x:
    for line in islice(f, 100, 150):
        print(line, file=x, end='')
```

or

```
with open('my_file.log', 'r') as f, \
     open('LocalLogFile.txt', 'a') as x:
    for line in islice(f, 100, 150):
        print(line, file=x, end='')
```

Python 3.10 will make it possible to parenthesize multiple context managers, allowing you to use multiple lines without explicit line continuation:

```
with (
    open('my_file.log', 'r') as f,
    open('LocalLogFile.txt', 'a') as x
):
    for line in islice(f, 100, 150):
        print(line, file=x, end='')
```

Comment: Cool, but `print(line, file=x)` gives exactly the output that OP doesn't want.

Comment: No, it doesn't; `line` is a *single* line from the file, not a list of lines.

Comment: (I did forget to either strip the newline from `line` or suppress the extra newline that `print` would output; I've fixed that now.)

Comment: The iSlice done the job ! thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to write out each line, not the Python representation of a list.

Also, use `with` to manage files.

```
with open('my_file.log', 'rb') as text_file:
    lines = list(text_file)  # same as readlines

lines = lines[100:150]

with open("LocalLogFile.txt", "a") as x:
    x.write("".join(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although other's answer valid a proper way to do this is

```py
with open('my_file.log', 'r') as f1:
    # f is an iterator
    # so instead of reading the whole file you can
    # go to the 100th line
    # suppose you you file has thousands of line

    for _ in range(100):
        next(f1)
        
    # now that you are at 100th line
    with open('LocalLogFile.txt', 'a') as f2:
        for i in range(50):
            f2.write(f1.readline())
            # no need to do next(f1 since f1.readline() will call next automatically)
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working : If I use your example 1:1 it is writing the information again in one long line but without the \n...second - I`m using variables instead of actual line number and when I put them instead - the file is empty - no errors in console. any ideas?

Comment: Tried the iSlice mentioned above - working OK now ...thanks :)

Comment: I removed the `'replace('\n', '')` which was replacing the newline character. Also with variable it should work just fine @TheWiz

Answer (score -1):

`x.write(''.join(lines))`

you are currently writing it as a representation of an array... but you need to write it as a string

Comment: There is no `join` method on arrays. It's `''.join(lines)`.